# Calculate UK Fiscal calendar week, period and year in PHP

Tags: php, date

I would like to determine the current Fiscal week period and year with a function when you pass it an empty argument, or the week, period and year of a datestring you include in the argument.

I have a function like this so far.

```php
function FiscalDates($date){
    $basedate=date_create("2018-04-29");
    $querydate=date_create($date);
    $diff=date_diff($basedate,$querydate);
    $days = $diff->format('%a'); 
    if(fmod($days,7)==0){
        $weekno = ($days/7)+1;
    } else {
        $weekno = ceil($days/7);
    }
    if(fmod($weekno,4)==0){
        $period = ($weekno/4);
    } else {
        $period = ceil($weekno/4);
    }
    if(fmod($period,13)==0){
        $year = ($period/13)-1;
    } else {
        $year = (ceil($period/13))-1;
    }
    $period = $period-(13*$year);
    $year = $year+2018;
    return array($weekno,$period,$year);
}
```

This works for the most part, but the only problem is that it does not account for the 'leap week' that happens every 5-6 years. (Where there is 53 weeks in the year) [see 2nd paragraph of this page about that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Every time this happens, the calculations will be off by another week.

How can I achieve a similar thing, but account for the 53 weeks in a year years and keep it accurate?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `return array($weekno,$period,$year);`
So if you then reference the function on another page like so:
`list($week,$period,$year) = FiscalDates("");`
You would get a return with the week period and year you can then use in your code on that php page.

Comment: Why not check for leap years and add another week?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late or not exactly a direct reply, but had similar issues a few years back for a UK business, so decided to work on a library that could prove helpful for you.

https://github.com/RoussKS/financial-year

It can get period/weeks for a financial year.
It handles 2 types of financial year. The standard 12 month (period) one, named `calendar` as a library convention, and `business` for 13 period financial years (for 52/53 weeks). `Business` is the one you would want to use.

It does not check when a year should be a 53 week year as this depends on the business, so you would need to provide that as a param (defaults to `false` aka 52).

Example use to fetch the period & week

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// DateTimeAdapter
// If instantiating with string, it must be of ISO-8601 format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
// This is your business's financial year start date.
$startDate = new \DateTime('2018-04-01');

$fy = new \RoussKS\FinancialYear\DateTimeAdapter('business', $startDate, false); // false for 52 weeks, true for 53 weeks

$dateToExamine = '2018-04-29';

// Get period of the date in question
echo $fy->getPeriodIdByDate($dateToExamine); // 1

// Get week of the date in question
echo $fy->getBusinessWeekIdIdByDate($dateToExamine); // 5
```

Not sure though what you mean by year, is it like naming the year as per 2018/2019?